# Canonical sheaf of Schubert cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, projective-geometry, grassmannians, schubert-calculus

Suppose we have a smooth subvariety $X\subset Gr(2,n)$ of a Grassmannian, that can be expressed as usual as a linear combination of Schubert cycles. I would like to obtain information on the canonical sheaf of $X$. Are there formulas for the canonical sheaf of Schubert cycles? Are there examples that I could check of such a computation?